# Sorting numbers and then letters in a string array

Tags: c#, .net

How to sort this on c#.Firstly I want to sort numbers & the letters alphabetically. Code is going no where ignore the other part of the code. Mostly interested in sorting it.

```
interface vehicle
{
    void Mon();
}

class order : vehicle
{
    public void Mon()
    {
        string[] arr = new string[]
        {
            "B $15",
            "A $251",
            "B $5",
            "B $25",
            "A $250",
            "A $45"
        };
    }
}
class ABC
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
 }
 }
```

so my expected result would be:

```
   A $5
   A $15
   A $25
   B $45
   B $250
   B $251
```

Comment: please provide an example of your expected result for clarity.

Comment: show us what you've tried, give us a clear example of what you want an how you want it sorted

Comment: @Valentin if your going to do that youll also have to cast to int and trim the $

Comment: @ibiza I have added it the required output .

Comment: First store your values in an actual data structure.  Then sorting becomes trivial.

Comment: @johnny 5  I have added it the required output

Comment: The output is letters first and th {} don't match up

Comment: Don't know why it went -5 for this question . Not a normal sorting .

Comment: The question has been downvoted because you did not even try to help yourself before asking. Your question showed no evidence that you had tried anything. It did not describe the desired output. We just have to guess at what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var lettersAndNumbers = arr.Select(x => x.Split('$'));
var orderedLetters = lettersAndNumbers.Select(x => x[0]).OrderBy(x => x);
var orderedNumbers = lettersAndNumbers.Select(x => int.Parse(x[1])).OrderBy(x => x);
string[] result = orderedLetters
    .Zip(orderedNumbers, (letter, number) => letter + "$" + number).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is looks like the best answer, splitting on the $ is a boss move

Comment: good usage of `Zip`! A little known LINQ operator that we should be using more instead of traditional for loops. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this, this is under the assumption that the format is correct.

```
var values = arr.Select(x => x.Split(' ')).ToList();

var strList = values.Select(x => x[0]).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

var intList = values.Select(x => Int32.Parse(x[1].SubString(1)))
                                                          .OrderBy(x => x).ToList();


foreach (var pair in strList.Zip(intList))
{
    //Do work with pair.Key and pair.Value
}
```

Comment: *.Skip()* Are you sure?

Comment: @xanatos your right I shouldn't do it that way it will convert to char array

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want *numbers* within the strings be compared as *numbers* (e.g. when comparing `"A $5"` and `"A $15"` we compare `"A $"` parts lexicogoraphically, while `5` and `15` as integers and thus `"A $5"` < `"A $15"`); in that case try this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string x, string y);

...

Array.Sort(arr, (left, right) => StrCmpLogicalW(
  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(left),
  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(right)));
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a reason why this got downvoted. Aside from David's recommendation to change the data type (which may not work if this is just a toy example), this is the ideal solution, since it leverages existing code that has been fully debugged and tested.

Comment: This won't work based on the users requirements, notice he is matching a's values with some of b's numbers

Comment: @johnny5 yes, OP changed its expected result while receiving answers.

Answer (score 0):

This outputs the expected result:

```
        string[] arr = new string[]
    {
        "B $15",
        "A $251",
        "B $5",
        "B $25",
        "A $250",
        "A $45"
    };
        var arrSplited = arr.Select(i => i.Split(' '));

        var letters = arrSplited
            .Select(i => i[0])
            .OrderBy(i => i)
            .ToArray();

        var numbers = arrSplited
            .Select(i => i[1])
            .OrderBy(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Replace("$", "").Trim()))
            .Select(i => i.ToString())
            .ToArray();

        var result = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
        {
            result.Add(letters[i]);
            result.Add(numbers[i]);
        }
```

Well, not anymore since you changed it in your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you *have* is one array of strings.  What you *want* is two arrays (one of characters or strings, and one of *numeric* data in order to achieve an intuitive sort).  Something like this:

```
var firstValues = new List<char> { 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A' };
var secondValues = new List<int> { 15, 251, 5, 25, 250, 45 };
```

Sort them each:

```
var sortedFirst = firstValues.OrderBy(v => v).ToList();
var sortedSecond = secondValues.OrderBy(v => v).ToList();
```

Then you can join them into a single data structure for your needs:

```
var sortedList = sortedFirst.Select((element, index) =>
    new { First = element, Second = sortedSecond[index] });
```

(Note that this assumes both lists are of the same length.  You can add some conditional checks to validate that just in case.)